# join and count query in flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have 2 tables one with names and id's and another with id's and dates,
I am trying to figure out how to create the helper method to query the two tables and return the list of names with the number of dates associated to their id.

```
Name Table
   id  Name
    1 John
    2 Tom
    3 Frank

Date Table
   id  Date
    1 1/3/19
    1 1/4/19
    1 1/5/19
    2 1/4/19

    Results:
    Name  Count
    John  3
    Tom   1
    Frank 0
```

This is as far as I have gotten just pulling back all the names.

```
  Future<List> queryAllNames() async {
    Database db = await database;
    List<Map> names =
        await db.query(Names, columns: [id, Name]);
    if (names.length > 0) {
      return names;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I have figured out the raw query I need from sqlite

```
select Name.name,  count(Date.date) from Name left join Date using(id) group by Name.name;
```

But still not able to translate to at sqflite helper method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a rawQuery() method. Check out [Raw SQL queries](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#raw-sql-queries)

Comment: Thanks that helped me get to this which works.
`Future<List> queryAll() async {
    Database db = await database;
    List<Map> names = await db.rawQuery(
        'select Name.name, count(Date.date) from Name left join Date using(id) group by Name.name');
    if (names.length > 0) {
      return names;
    }
    return null;
  }`